# How to get apacite with square brackets and numbers

Tags: packages, brackets, apacite

I've been trying for a while and I am wondering how can I get an APA 5th styled bibliography but in the text I want citations like:

> " ... blablabla [1]."

And in the bibliography it should look like:

> [1] Zhang, K., Kemme, B. & Denault, A. (2008). Persistence in massively multiplayer
>   online games. In Proceedings of the 7th acm sigcomm workshop
>   on network and system support for games (S. 53-58).

I use these commands:

```
\usepackage[]{apacite}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
```

and currently I am getting in text citations like:

> bla bla bla (Zhang, 2008).

and a bibligraphy which looks like:

> Zhang, K., Kemme, B. & Denault, A. (2008). Persistence in massively multiplayer online games. In Proceedings of the 7th acm sigcomm workshop
>   on network and system support for games (S. 53-58).

Also i'm also getting a lot of entries with (o. J.) = "ohne Jahr" = without year"

> Valve Corporation. (o. J.-e). Demo Recording Tools. Zugriff am 25.02.2016
>   auf https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Demo_Recording_Tools

How can i get rid of these?

Help appreciated :)

Comment: You're asking for something that is absolutely *not* APA style, so you shouldn't be surprised that it doesn't work. What would you prefer for your no date items?

Comment: What styling is this then. I just got a reference paper where i was told it is cited wth APA 5th Edition and i looked like this. Most importantly i dont want round brackets. Just square brackets and numbers. and for no date items i would like to have no date ;) (and no "(o.J.)")